# Add background colour to Theorem Header only

Tags: math-mode, formatting

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,
bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{refcount} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
{4pt}                                           % ABOVESPACE
{6pt}                                           % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape\color{blue}}                              % BODYFONT
{6pt}                                           % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\color{DarkRed}\bfseries}% HEADFONT
{\:.}                                           % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}    % HEADSPACE
{}                                              % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{12pt}
\section{Section ONE}

\begin{theorem}
Theorem 1
\end{theorem}

\theorem{Theorem 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you minimize your code and ask a human-to-human question?

Comment: The \newtheoremstyle code is part of the question; there is little I can do to lessen the code.  The line {\color{DarkRed}\bfseries} controls the text font - I want to add a background colour to that text.

Comment: It should be doable with the `thmtools` package (which cooperates with `amsthm`).

Comment: Would Bernard be kind enough to take this a little further, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I like the following new solution better, which uses the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,
bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{refcount} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
{4pt}                    % ABOVESPACE
{6pt}                    % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape\color{blue}}   % BODYFONT
{6pt}                    % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{}                       % HEADFONT
{}                       % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
                         % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
{\raisebox{0pt}{{%\frame{\colorbox{yellow}
    {%
    \textbf{%
      \bfseries%
      \tcbox[size=title, on line, hbox, colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black]{%
      \textcolor{DarkRed}{%
        \thmname{#1}%
        \thmnumber{ #2}%
        \thmnote{ (#3)}%
        .%
      }%
      }%
    }%
  }}}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{12pt}
\section{Section ONE}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem 1
\end{theorem}

\theorem{Theorem 2}

\theorem[note]{Theorem 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Below is my original solution using `\frame` and `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{newtxmath} %
\usepackage[dvipsname]{xcolor} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,
bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} 
\usepackage{refcount} %
\usepackage{hyperref} %
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{rgb}{0.45,0.06,0.06} % #880000
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
{4pt}                    % ABOVESPACE
{6pt}                    % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape\color{blue}}   % BODYFONT
{6pt}                    % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{}                       % HEADFONT
{}                       % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
                         % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
{\raisebox{-3pt}{\frame{\colorbox{yellow}{%
    \textbf{%
      \bfseries%
      \textcolor{DarkRed}{%
        \thmname{#1}%
        \thmnumber{ #2}%
        \thmnote{ (#3)}%
        .%
      }%
    }%
  }}}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{theorem}{section}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{12pt}
\section{Section ONE}

\begin{theorem}
  Theorem 1
\end{theorem}

\theorem{Theorem 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @keith77777, the #1 stands for the second parameter of `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Comment: @keith77777, you can check the documentation of `amsthm` for more information of `newtheoremstyle`: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm

Comment: modnar; can you refine your solution to include a border around the yellow background, please? \colorbox itself does not appear to allow such options.

Comment: @keith77777, done!

Comment: Thanks for a prompt and effective reply.

Comment: @keith77777, you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

OK, first let’s fix some of the glaring issues here.

1. The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around your `\theoremstyle` are unnecessary. Delete them. Kill them with fire.
2. It seems to me a bug that `\newtheoremstyle` lets you overwrite a theorem style without so much as a warning. I would suggest that you instead write

   ```
   \newtheoremstyle{color}
      ... all the bits of declaration here
   \theoremstyle{color}
   \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
   ```
3. I've seen variations on

   ```
   \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
   \counterwithin*{theorem}{section}
   ```

   enough that I think people are forgetting the optional arguments of `\newtheorem`. I would recommend instead of the above formulation to instead write:

   ```
   \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % ❶
   \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thetheorem}{}{\arabic{theorem}} % ❷
   ```

   using the trailing optional argument ❶ on `\newtheorem` to specify the numbering within and then redefining¹<sup>,</sup>² `\thetheorem` ❷ to omit the section number.³
4. It's pure happenstance that `\section{Theorem 2}` doesn't throw an error, but it should be

   ```
   \begin{theorem}
   Theorem 2
   \end{theorem}
   ```

   as you would quickly discover if there was anything after `\section{Theorem 2}` in the document.
5. Commands like `\vspace` really don't belong in a document. If you want extra space there, you should modify the document class to insert it before a `\section`, not throw a bit of visual formatting in like this, especially for something that's being submitted for publication. It looks like in this instance you may have put it in because you've messed up your page geometry and have the header line overprinting the text block÷

**And now an answer to the actual question**

If you want to add a background color to the head only, you need to do this with the final argument to `\newtheoremstyle`.

The default setting for the final argument is not really documented anywhere, but it ends up being:⁴⁵

```
\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \textup{#2}}% ❸
  \thmnote{ {\fontseries\mddefault\upshape(#3)}}
```

The call to `\textup` ❸ appears to be redundant as near as I can tell, but it's worth being aware of should you have desired to label a theorem as ***Theorem 1*** and wondered why it came out as ***Theorem* 1** instead.

The macros `\thmname`, `\thmnumber` and `\thmnote` check to see if their associated parameters are provided. If they are not, then the contents of the argument are ignored which is an easy way to get rid of, say, the space between the theorem number and the theorem if the number isn't present. We'll assume that at least one of the enunciation name (e.g., “Theorem”) and the number are present in coming up with an alternative definition. We can just use

```
\colorbox{pink}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \textup{#2}}}%
   \thmnote{ {\fontseries\mddefault\upshape(#3)}}
```

That said, the head punctuation will appear outside the colorbox, and I have to assume that the `\:` before the period was a mistake because I can't imagine anyone intentionally wanting that large ugly space before a period. It looks better to bring the period inside the colorbox via the custom head spec. You might want also to bring the `\thmnote` inside the color box as well, but it's up to you. Here's a complete `\newthoremstyle`:

```
\newtheoremstyle{color}
    {4pt}                                           % ABOVESPACE
    {6pt}                                           % BELOWSPACE
    {\itshape\color{blue}}                              % BODYFONT
    {6pt}                                           % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
    {\color{DarkRed}\bfseries}% HEADFONT
    {}                                           % HEADPUNCT
    {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}    % HEADSPACE
    {\colorbox{pink}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \textup{#2}}.}%
       \thmnote{ {\fontseries\mddefault\upshape(#3)}}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
```

---

1. Yes, I'm going to hammer at using `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends until I never see another `\newcommand` etc. again.
2. Worth noting that we use `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand` here so that we will get the correct value of the theorem number in references, etc.
3. Although if you do this, you really should consider defining `\p@theorem` to add the section number back in to references to make it clear *which* theorem 1 is being referred to.
4. I've replaced some internal macro definitions for the sake of clarity.
5. There's one other thing in there as well—the default setting of the contents of `\thmnumber` looks to see if there was a theorem label provided and if not, omits the space. This allows you to the somewhat weird thing of:

   ```
    \newtheorem{foo}{}
   ```

   to get a numbered theorem that has no label but does have a number. This could actually be handy for exercise lists.

Comment: Thank you for for raising so many useful points.  The inclusion of #1, #2 and #3 in the eighth argument of \newtheorem style renders the call in \begin{document  ... \end{document} quite different from normal.  Can you complete the picture, please, by giving a MWE.  In my view, the users would then be better able trace through and see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Modnar; thanks, that's just what I wanted.  Can you explain, please, why you use #1, #2 and #3 in the formatting, yet there appear to be no options necessary in the calls.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty as far as I understand the protocol.